# PHP vld shows file output instead of opcode

Tags: php, apache, opcode, php-opcode

I'm trying to use vld to view opcode of a php file

## prep

I've installed vld with:

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/vld-0.12.0
```

To get familiar with VLD, I'm trying to compare to php files (echo1 and echo2)

echo1.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello"." "."World";
```

echo2.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello"," ","World";
```

phpinfo() shows that vld seems to be enabled:

```
vld support        enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
vld.active         0    0
vld.col_sep             
vld.dump_paths     1    1
vld.execute        1    1
vld.format         0    0
vld.save_dir       /tmp /tmp
vld.save_paths     0    0
vld.skip_append    0    0
vld.skip_prepend   0    0
vld.verbosity      1    1
```

## problem

running php files shows output instead of opcode

```
# php -dvld.active=1 -f echo1.php
Hello World

# php -dvld.active=1 -dvld.execute=0 -f echo1.php
Hello World

# php -dvld.active=1 -f echo2.php
Hello World

# php -dvld.active=1 -dvld.execute=0 -f echo2.php
Hello World
```

Obviously I'm missing something :)

## versions running

php version

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u14 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2014 08:36:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Running Debian in Virtualbox with Apache 2.2.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating to PHP 5.6.2 I gave it another go and it is running :)

php version

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2014 07:22:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

install pear

```
yum install php56w-pear
```

installing vld

```
pecl install vld
```

add extension to /etc/php.ini (or in file in /etc/php.d/__.ini)

```
#/etc/php.d/vld.ini
extension=vld.so
```

restart httpd service and test again (fingers crossed)

```
 # php -dvld.active=1 -f echo1.php
 Finding entry points
 Branch analysis from position: 0
 Jump found. Position 1 = -2
 filename:       /var/www/html/echo1.php
 function name:  (null)
 number of ops:  4
 compiled vars:  none
 line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2     0  E >   CONCAT                                           ~0      'Hello', '+'
          1        CONCAT                                           ~1      ~0, 'World'
          2        ECHO                                                     ~1
    3     3      > RETURN                                                   1

 branch: #  0; line:     2-    3; sop:     0; eop:     3; out1:  -2
 path #1: 0,
 Hello World
```

**Boom Baby!**

I don't know why, but it is working as expected :)

Now the OPCODE adventures can begin (also a love story)

Answer (score 0):

You might be add `extension.so` to wrong php.ini file

You might be add the extension to php.ini that use by your webserver instead of cli version

What you can do is run `locate php.ini`, and choose the cli version of php.ini and add `extension.so` to that file

Normally cli version of php.ini located at `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Dont forget to restart your console too

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i do not have this cli php.ini file.
`locate php.ini` only showed `/etc/php.ini`

Double checked this with `php -i | grep php.ini`
`Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini`